# Java/Postgres/JPA : PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have a one to many relationship between "code" and "code system" (a code system has many codes.)  I implemented my service with the following to save codes for code systems:

**service**

```
    code = new Code();
    code.setCode(valueConcept.getCode());
    code.setName(valueConcept.getDisplay_name());
    code.setValueSet(valueSet);
    code.setCodeSystem(codeSystem);
    code.setDateCreated(new Date());
    code.setDateUpdated(new Date());
    codeRepository.save(code);
```

The last line of the code is throwing the exception.  "Code System" is an object which is created above using a similar JPA repository.

To implement this one to many relationship I have the following two entity classes:

**Code.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "codeCode_idGenerator")
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "\"CODE_ID\"", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "codeCode_idGenerator", sequenceName = "crisp_pophealth.application.code_id_seq", schema = "application", catalog = "crisp_pophealth")
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;

}

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
@Basic(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "\"CODE_SYSTEM_ID\"", nullable = true)
public CodeSystem getCodeSystem() {
    return this.codeSystem;

}
```

**CodeSystem.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "codeSystemRecord_idGenerator")
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "\"RECORD_ID\"", nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "codeSystemRecord_idGenerator", sequenceName = "crisp_pophealth.application.code_system_id_seq", schema = "application", catalog = "crisp_pophealth")
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;

}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "codeSystem")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "\"RECORD_ID\"", nullable = false)
public Set<Code> getCodes() {
    return this.codes;

}
```

The reason the sequences are set the way they are is because the primary key is defined as follows on each postgres table (as an example):

```
    CREATE TABLE application.code ("CODE_ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('application.code_id_seq'::regclass),
```

What's the best way annotate the classes for this relation to exist?  I'm using the sequence strategy AUTO since the database is managing sequence values on creation.  I've tried saving unsuccessfully using an entity manager, but I would prefer to have all persistence managed by these JPA repository classes.